# Is it possible to hide other applications from our application?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I have a project in this have to hide other applications from my application.Means can I hide all application installed in my iphone device through a application ?

My question is that is it possible to hide other application and folders from our application ? please share any reference url for answer.

And I have a reference application [KeepSafe](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/hide-photos-with-keepsafe/id510873505?mt=8) in that user can hide pictures and video for securities

Comment: what applications in your application? your question is really unclear.

Comment: Need to create a application, through that application need to  hide all application installed in my iphone device.

Comment: When you run your application.It just directly hides(send to background) all other applications.Just notifications remains active if notification is there in applications

Comment: As far as I know KeepSafe and other apps like that, just copy the pictures and videos to the application and only let you open them with a password, but the videos and pictures are on the gallery too, so you have to delete them manually from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, it isn't.

Slightly longer answer: Look up the Apple guide to how iOS apps are sandboxed here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html

You can't affect apps (or indeed much else) outside of your sandboxed environment unless there's an API to do so in one of the frameworks. As far as I know there is no such API to hide the icons of other apps.